# How to create .appxsym for zipping .appxupload

Tags: windows-store-apps, package, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I convert desktop apps to Universal Windows Platform apps with Desktop Bridge.
I have file .appx And Floder PackageFiles. 
I know .appxupload make by  zipped  .appx and .appxsym (public symbols), renamed to '.appxupload'.
But How to create .appxsym file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But How to create .appxsym file.

You can use [PDBCopy.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-pdbcopy) to copy all PDB files related to all dll, exe or winmd libraries without private symbols. This tool takes a symbol file that contains both private symbol data and a public symbol table, and creates a copy of that file that contains only the public symbol table.

These PDB symbols can be zipped into .appxsym file.

When generate your package using Visual Studio, checking the includes the symbols allows you to generate the appxupload file ready to submit to the Store:
[image]

For the details, see [**Package a .NET app using Visual Studio (Desktop Bridge)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net#generate-packages-for-your-desktop-bridge-app).

A regular .appx file can be submitted to the Store as well, although there will be no crash analytic or debugging information available.

Comment: A regular .appx file can be submitted to the Store as well, although there will be no crash analytic or debugging information available. 
This appx file ca submitted to the Store or appx in zip to appxupload?

Comment: The .appx file can be submitted to the Store but you need to fill out and submit the [Desktop Bridge form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) to acquire the permission.

Comment: When uploading the appx file create DAC (Desktop app converter) I am getting this following error:
 A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows 10 appxbundle. Subsequent submissions must continue to contain a Windows 10 appxbundle.